# Example deegree configuration which supports multiple user styles for the same feature type?

Tags: style, sld, deegree

I am running [deegree](https://www.deegree.org/about-deegree/) 3.4 on Windows 10 and I would like know how to create a deegree configuration that supports multiple user styles for the same feature type. I am using BLOB mode.

Does anyone have an example of this?

My current configuration is not working:

LAYER CONFIG:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FeatureLayers xmlns="http://www.deegree.org/layers/feature" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:l="http://www.deegree.org/layers/base" xmlns:plu="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/plu/4.0/PlannedLandUse.xsd" xmlns:d="http://www.deegree.org/metadata/description" xmlns:s="http://www.deegree.org/metadata/spatial" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.deegree.org/layers/feature http://schemas.deegree.org/layers/feature/3.4.0/feature.xsd"
  configVersion="3.4.0">
  <FeatureStoreId>multi_style</FeatureStoreId>
  <FeatureLayer>
    <FeatureType>plu:SpatialPlan</FeatureType>
    <l:Name>LU.SpatialPlan</l:Name>
    <d:Title>LandUse.SpatialPlan.Default</d:Title>
    <!-- 
    <s:CRS>EPSG:26912 EPSG:4326 EPSG:4258 CRS:84</s:CRS>
     -->
    <l:StyleRef>
      <l:StyleStoreId>multi_style_sld</l:StyleStoreId>
      <l:Style>
        <l:StyleName>LandUse.SpatialPlan.Default</l:StyleName>
        <l:LayerNameRef>LU.SpatialPlan</l:LayerNameRef>
        <l:StyleNameRef>LandUse.SpatialPlan.Default</l:StyleNameRef>
    </l:Style>
    <l:Style>
        <l:StyleName>LandUse.SpatialPlan.Pink</l:StyleName> 
        <l:LayerNameRef>LU.SpatialPlan</l:LayerNameRef> 
        <l:StyleNameRef>LandUse.SpatialPlan.Pink</l:StyleNameRef> 
    </l:Style>
    </l:StyleRef>
  </FeatureLayer>
</FeatureLayers>
```

THEME CONFIG:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Themes configVersion="3.4.0" xmlns="http://www.deegree.org/themes/standard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:d="http://www.deegree.org/metadata/description"
  xmlns:s="http://www.deegree.org/metadata/spatial" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.deegree.org/themes/standard http://schemas.deegree.org/themes/3.4.0/themes.xsd">

  <LayerStoreId>multi_style_layer</LayerStoreId>

  <Theme>
    <Identifier>base</Identifier>
    <d:Title>Root theme</d:Title>
    <s:CRS>EPSG:4326</s:CRS>
    <Theme>
      <Identifier>LU.SpatialPlan</Identifier>
      <d:Title>SpatialPlan</d:Title>
      <Layer>LU.SpatialPlan</Layer>
    </Theme>
  </Theme>

</Themes>
```

STYLES CONFIG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se"
  version="1.1.0" xmlns:app="http://www.deegree.org/app" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sed="http://www.deegree.org/se"
  xmlns:deegreeogc="http://www.deegree.org/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>LU.SpatialPlan</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>LandUse.SpatialPlan.Default</se:Name>

        <se:FeatureTypeStyle  xmlns:plu="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/plu/4.0" 
        xmlns:net="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0" 
        xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
        xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" 
        xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        version="1.1.0" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/se http://schemas.opengis.net/se/1.1.0/FeatureStyle.xsd">
            <se:Name>LandUse.SpatialPlan.Default</se:Name>
            <se:Description>
                <se:Title>Planned Land Use Default Style</se:Title>
                <se:Abstract>This Style defines the default INSPIRE style for spatial plans. Spatial plan extents are represented by black (#000000) lines of 2 pixels.</se:Abstract> 
            </se:Description>
            <se:FeatureTypeName>plu:SpatialPlan</se:FeatureTypeName>
            <se:Rule>
            <se:Description>
                <se:Title>Spatial plan</se:Title>
            </se:Description>
            <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Geometry>
                <ogc:PropertyName>plu:extent</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Geometry>
            <se:Stroke>
                <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
                <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
            </se:LineSymbolizer>
            </se:Rule>
        </se:FeatureTypeStyle>

    </UserStyle>
  
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>LandUse.SpatialPlan.Pink</se:Name>

        <se:FeatureTypeStyle  xmlns:plu="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/plu/4.0" 
        xmlns:net="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0" 
        xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
        xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" 
        xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        version="1.1.0" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/se http://schemas.opengis.net/se/1.1.0/FeatureStyle.xsd">
            <se:Name>LandUse.SpatialPlan.Pink</se:Name>
            <se:Description>
                <se:Title>Planned Land Use Pink Style</se:Title>
                <se:Abstract>This Style defines the pink style for spatial plans. Spatial plan extents are represented by pink (##F699CD) lines of 4 pixels.</se:Abstract> 
            </se:Description>
            <se:FeatureTypeName>plu:SpatialPlan</se:FeatureTypeName>
            <se:Rule>
            <se:Description>
                <se:Title>Spatial plan</se:Title>
            </se:Description>
            <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Geometry>
                <ogc:PropertyName>plu:extent</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Geometry>
            <se:Stroke>
                <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#F699CD</se:SvgParameter>
                <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.4</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
            </se:LineSymbolizer>
            </se:Rule>
        </se:FeatureTypeStyle>

    </UserStyle>

  </NamedLayer>

</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I had `xmlns:plu="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/plu/4.0/PlannedLandUse.xsd"`  declared in the layer config, instead of `xmlns:plu="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/plu/4.0`.